# No results from TCPDUMP

Tags: tcpdump

I have a solar panel inverter which is wifi connected. When I run `tcpdump` I get zero output. I know it's using the wifi because when the broadband went down for several hours there was nothing reported in the app. It reports at 5 minute intervals.

```
#!/bin/bash

script=`basename $0`

date=`date +%F_%H%M%S`

nohup tcpdump 'host 47.91.67.66 or host 192.168.0.75' -w $script-$date.pcap &
PID=$!
echo $PID > $script.pid
```

47.91.67.66 is the server, 192.168.0.75 is the inverter.

```
tcpdump: listening on enp6s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Comment: Are you capturing this on your router or access point? Else one can expect to not find anything, even if ARP was added to the capture (because some AP do isolation and other tricks).

Comment: This is on machine in the network

Comment: I can  capture stuff from other devices on the network

Comment: You will not see traffic coming from your inverter unless you are running `tcpdump` on the network gateway (or on the inverter itself).

Comment: Is this machine running `tcpdump` on a wired connection or sniffing wireless? (Interface `enp6s0` looks like it might be wired.)